# Can I safely ignore the Key length restriction warning in ABAP?

Tags: abap

I am creating an module that is supposed to run on different customer systems - ECC 6.0 base --> ECC 6.0 EhP7.

Now, upon creating a table, I get this "warning". Of course the overall length of the PK is ~280.

The only problem would be that I cannot create a lock on this table. Apart from that is there any other problem?

```
Table ZTAB: Key length > 120 (restricted functions)
Message no. DT214

Diagnosis

The key length, that is, the sum of the field lengths of all the key fields of the table, is greater than 120 bytes.

System Response

This is a warning.

Procedure

Note the following restricted fuctionality for this table:
- Table contents cannot be transported by specifying key values, at
  most, by specifying generic
  key values with a maximum length of 120 bytes.

The table cannot be used as the base table of a lock object if the total of
  the fields lengths of all key fields in the table is greater than 150 bytes.
```

Comment: The consequences are stated rather clearly in the message: generic transport only, no lock objects. In most cases I have experienced, a primary key that large has turned out to be a design issue.

Comment: I have to parse an xml and store it as CNAME and CVALUE. CNAME is of Char255 and it's the primary key.  Alternatively, I can generate a 32 digit guid for every entry to work around this. Is that a valid option in ABAP?

Comment: What do you know about your xml? Is the purpose of your XML a generic key value store or is it something more specific?

Comment: GUID is quite valid as a key. Why not?

Comment: Yes, GUID is a valid key. But OP should think about why CNAME was originally chosen as the key. Maybe there is a better solution than just setting something as a PK.

Comment: @GerdCastan the XML could be any xml. There 3 or 4 variants possible. So, I have to convert an incoming xml to a flat format (with Hierarchy and Type (A,V, '',+)) and store that for future fetches.

So, I either increment an id and store it against each line entry or create a guid for each entry - thus making each line item unique.

Comment: @Brian CNAME is chose to be a primary key because the XML/s that get ingested vary anywhere between 512kb to 5mb of data, thus creating anywhere between 10,000 to 5,000,000 lines of data. There are usecases that search for a CNAME - hence was thinking of having CNAME as the key. If that's somehow not ok, I plan on creating an additional index on CNAME.

Comment: So you want to represent an arbitrary xml - including attributes, element hierarchys, namespaces, entitys, texts with arbitrary lengthy, comments, [CDATA[...]], Processing instructions... so you can address each element, attribute etc as a table row?

Comment: Usually I'd use an extreme approach: not interpret the XML all and store ist as some form of CLOB. There are a few ways to do that. Or I'd interpret and model the content: so when the XML data represents a customer, I'd model a customer with name, Address and whatever is represented in the XML. I didn't perceive any reason to do something in between.

Comment: :) I was exactly doing that. Storing the entire xml into a hex RAWSTRING. The UI written that's eventually consuming this content as API is written in AngularJS and it's easier for them to have JSON.
Hence I flatten an incoming XML into {id, hier, type, cname}, convert it into a JSON in an SICF handler and throw it out as a JSON response to an incoming http GET req on the ICF node.

Comment: @lonelymo it sounds like your question "Apart from that is there any other problem?" has been answered as no, but your design may not make sense.

Maybe you should provide more information, such as what your REST API looks like, which may explain why your proposed need of CNAME as a key makes or does not make sense.